# Saving data of a function without use of Globals

Tags: python, function

below is my attempted function:

```
 def function(x):
        list1 = []
        if("word" in x):
          print("Option 1: XXX, Option 2: YYY ...")
          list1.extend(input("Enter a word: "))
```

What I'm attempting to do here is to place the value X with a string of my choosing (a question to the user) and have the user enter their answer. I then want to add that answer to a list that is **NOT** a global variable (As this is the main point I'm avoiding) without having that list be wiped everytime I call this function; as I wish to call function(x) several times for several questions. After this is done, I also need to be able to pull this list and pass it to another function so that math etc. can be done on the users answers.

Any advice at all? If you could EXPLAIN what's going on as well I would really appreciate it as I'm struggling to grasp what's actually happening here. I've been told that placing the list in the function argument works (and it does) but this doesn't allow me to later take the list and do things to it (and is apparently a bug in python). Running a loop for this also doesn't help much.

EDIT: I'll be back in a few hours and will mark an answer then; haven't read through them all yet but so far I think I'm getting a handle on it.

Comment: Why not returning string from the function and then defining and extending the list in the calling function.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: "and is apparently a bug in python". Whoever told you that doesn't understand the fundamentals of Python's data model. I recommend [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables), and [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for further details.

Comment: The statement `if ("word" in x)` will be True if x has "word" in it, x can be "words", "swords", "skdjghkdgword"... What is the point of this in your code?

Comment: I've got very specific questions being asked to the user that contain a specific keyword in them (i.e gender, sex). Its to test if the question is one of these; otherwise it'll run generic code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called a `static` in languages like C.  Python does not need such a keyword because it is so flexible.  One way to achieve it is to use a *closure* which maintains encapsulation.  You will notice that the `setupf` function returns two internal functions, whose names can be anything that's legal.

```
def setupf():
    list1 = []    # This is the "static" variable

    def internal(x):
        if ("word" in x):
            print("Option 1: XXX, Option 2: YYY ...")
            list1.append(input("Enter a word: "))

    def getit():
        return list1

    return internal, getit


function, getlist = setupf()

function("word")
function("word")
function("word")
function("word")

print(getlist())
```

Gives:

```
Option 1: XXX, Option 2: YYY ...
Enter a word: hello
Option 1: XXX, Option 2: YYY ...
Enter a word: goodbye 
Option 1: XXX, Option 2: YYY ...
Enter a word: stuff
Option 1: XXX, Option 2: YYY ...
Enter a word: another
['hello', 'goodbye', 'stuff', 'another']
```

You might notice I replaced `.extend` with `.append` - in the C implementation of Python using `.append` is more efficient because of the way lists are implemented.

I am puzzled by the test for "word", perhaps you could explain.

Comment: The word test is for my specific thing, I am asking specific questions to the user than have keywords.

This is a very nice answer, and I never knew you could have functions within functions. It's 1am here at time of writing; when I get back and read through the others properly I'll mark one as answered, but this seems very straightforward (and keeps the lists local from what I can tell). Thank you!!

Comment: @pixelrain: glad to help, and I understand that this might be daunting for a beginner.  Functions within functions are a powerful feature, C, C++, and Java had to implement lambdas to achieve this (python has lambdas as well of course).  I'll for offline for a few days, but if you have any specific questions I'll try to answer them next week.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `return` to avoid using `global` variables

```
def function(x):
    answer = "n/a"
    if("word" in x): # test if x contains "word", not sure why you have this
        print("Option 1: XXX, Option 2: YYY ...")
        answer = input("Enter a word: ")

    return answer # this is the value given when the function is called

list1 = []
list1.append(function("...")) # add the value returned by the function
list1.append(function("..."))
...
```

Comment: Further clarification- every place you call a function it gets "replaced" by whatever it returns. So if you write `result = function()`, then result will be assigned to whatever `function()` returns.

Comment: @PM2Ring, eddited

Comment: So I can call the function within itself?

Comment: What I'm getting from this (Correct me if wrong) is that we have a generic question/input function, and within this function at the bottom we run the first section over and over to get new answers which we keep adding to the list (all within the same function). Is that right?

Comment: You are right, but the function in this case, the function isn't being called within itself. In the last 3 lines of the code, I could've had `answer = function("...")` then `list1.append(answer)`, it would work just the same

Comment: So wait, is this list a global list or is it local to this function? The function is equal to the inputted answer; how does this input then get added to the list? Is there another function you've omitted (...) or am I just not following? Sorry for being a pain!

Comment: No problem :), the list `list1` is a local variable, it is not part of any function. The input `answer` is a variable inside `function(x)`. Using `return` allows the variable `answer` to be copied to another variable (or in this case added to the list) outside the function. So if you were to `print(function("word"))` the output would be the variable answer.